# Can I grow in my current company or am I wasting my time?

Tags: career-development

I’ve been at current company for over 4 years .

In my current department , I’ve been here over 2 years.

The current issue is where in those 2 years , I have had no promotions and it seems like other people in the department are getting promoted ahead of me or being put forward for more senior roles.

A bit of background:

Upon joining this department I really got on with my manager at the time.

They left, where that manager was replaced with one I really did not get on with at all. Things got so bad between us, to the point that they bad mouthed me to the rest of the leadership team and even became so vindictive to the point that they told my current manager to give me a poor performance review - which they didn’t. They are a long term employee in that department and is good friends with the leadership team.

Anyway, that manager made a mess of the situation generally managing the teams, and was replaced by my current manager who I get on with.

Since current manager has joined , even though we get on , and there are no issues between us.

It seems as though he is struggling to get me pay rises and promotions. Yet at the same time, it seems as though others are - immediate peers or others.

I’ve asked my manager what I needed to do to get considered for promotions, where I have done those things but he still can’t deliver. He’s getting blocked by his boss.

When asked , he tries to justify it over x, y reason, where the bar is being set super high. Yet I’m seeing the people getting promoted doing much less, or the equivalent where the only thing that they have in common between each other is where managers like them on a personal level.

Vibe I’m sensing, although not confirmed, is where the other managers do not like me on a personal level after the falling out with my past manager and are making it awkward and difficult for me to progress my career within the org.

So the question is where if that is the case, am I wasting my time being here or is it time to leave org?

Comment: Yeah @JoeStrazzere, getting into final rounds but falling short currently. Will keep trying though.

Comment: You do realize that the wording of the question answers itself.

Comment: I guess I’m in denial , hoping things will get better

Comment: Not necessarily. Your wording suggests that you are trying to justify a decision you have already made, or at least are leaning towards. I don't feel I have enough data to advise you on that choice. Do _you_ think you can make the current job work well enough to be worth staying?

Comment: @keshlam I’m conflicted because my current boss and team are fine, the issue is beyond that. Boss’s manager and the wider leadership team seem to be holding me back, by not recognising any of the work I do. I’m hoping that can change but it doesn’t look like it.

Comment: We don't have the info to answer that. I'm afraid it has to be your own best judgement. Since you like your manager, I would recommend you discuss your frustrations with them and see if they can either do something to help or convince you that this will change.

Answer (score 5):

> So the question is where if that is the case, am I wasting my time
> being here or is it time to leave org?

There's no way anyone outside the organization can know. But it seems that if promotions are important to you, then you are wasting your time there and it's time to move on.

- You have stated that there are no opportunities to develop skills required by other companies.
- You are bothered by obstructive colleagues.
- You have concluded that a former manager is trying to damage your reputation and growth opportunities within the company.
- You feel that a devious colleague is intentionally witholding key information, not inviting you to key meetings, and giving you misinformation.

If you have someone within the organization that you like and trust, you could run it by them for an inside opinion. But based on what you have written, it seems obvious.

Since you are already interviewing elsewhere, I'm guessing you have already reached a similar conclusion.

Comment: Sums it up well. That devious colleague btw is an example of someone who just keeps on getting promoted, and what people are like here.

Answer (score 5):

> So the question is where if that is the case, am I wasting my time being here or is it time to leave org?

Does it matter if it is the case? You do not get what you want. Whether it is a promotion or pay raise or more PTO, there is something you want and don't get.

Does it matter what the reason is? Would you feel better and want to stay if the reason was something else? A policy that they don't promote people with odd social security numbers in even years? Or don't give pay raises to people who like "Star Wars" because the management is all Trekkies? Would there really be something where you would go "oh, yeah, that's fair, I don't need a promotion then"?

Their reasoning is probably complex, hard to grasp and even harder to change. As always, the only question that is important, is "Can you get a better job?"

So go and find out.